# EventBrite API call for removing a contact from a contact list

Tags: eventbrite

Does anyone know if there is a method in the EventBrite API for removing a contact from a contact list? I'm not seeing one in the documentation (http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/#methods), but there is apparently contact list functionality that is not documented there, as seen in this helpful gist:
https://gist.github.com/ryanj/6a66d93a54a69d4e3f50

That gist documents a contact_list_update method which is useful for adding contacts to a list but not for removing contacts from a list. Thanks in advance to anyone who has experience with this area of the EventBrite API!

Answer (score 0):

You can delete an entire contact list (documented in the gist that you linked to), but there isn't a way to delete an individual contact from a list.

As a work around, you could pull a full list, remove the individual contact, create a new list, then delete the old list -- although, I realize that this isn't ideal.

Sorry about that! Cheers!